# What does "generally" means in "Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right"?

Tags: mysql

I read this in MySQL docs for a while

> Single-table UPDATE assignments are **generally** evaluated from left to right.

It's the same since 5.6

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

What does "generally" means here? I never encountered any case where this left-to-right order is not honored, but in such case, why would documentation not be simply "Single-table UPDATE assignments are evaluated from left to right"?

This may sound quibbling but the "generally" word makes me think (as non-english native maybe) that "there are some cases where order might not be left-to-right, but we won't tell which ones (because we don't know)"...

Comment: Ah, how I hate vague docs! This makes me think of [`Hibernate.initialize(...)`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize-java.lang.Object-): "it is not guaranteed that the elements INSIDE the collection will be initialized/materialized"... So what, will they be or will they be not?

Comment: Well, `update t set a = b, b = a` isn't really evaluated from left to right (because the values aren't correctly swapped)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it seems L2R evaled to me, like a=1,b=2 => a=b so a=2,b=2 => b=a so a=2,b=2 but maybe it's the reason why doc says that (tho, it's good to me, it means "guaranteed order" one-by-one)

Comment: *What does "generally" means here?* It means "but not always", "with no guarantee".

Comment: @Xenos Well, if you start with `a = 1, b = 2` that update statement should result in `a = 2, b = 1` according to the SQL standard (and what every other DBMS does)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah, makes sense then! Do you have a link to SQL standard for UPDATE statement that states this behavior? that would certainly answer my question